# why cant i check my checkbox by clicking on he label in my phonegap android app?

Tags: checkbox, cordova, label

i use a checkbox in my phonegap android app like this:

```
<div style="margin-top: 35px;" class="" id="divSaveUserDataCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="saveUserDataCheckbox" >  </input>
<label id="labelForSaveUserData" for="saveUserDataCheckbox" style="font-size:100%;padding-top: 25px">save login</label>
</div>
```

i want to check my checkbox by clicking on the label but this doesnt work, why? Shouldnt this work out o the box?

greets,
Tom

Comment: did you found a solution? I have the same issue, and have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: i added the "ontouchstart=function()" Parameter and select the checkbox in the function

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found my problem. I was using FastClick, to disable the waiting time between "tap" and "doubletap". But this blocked partially somehow the checkbox clicks. I'm not creating a webapp, just a website, so it's not so important for me, but if you find some workaround, please write a comment :)